# Which hemisphere of the earth gets more sunlight?

Tags: orbital-motion

This question is for amusement only so to speak...

Which hemisphere of the earth gets more sunlight, northern or southern?

By "gets more sunlight" let's say we're counting photons over the course of one average year (pretend the sun radiates uniformly).

The earth is closer to the sun during the southern summer, so that would argue for the southern hemisphere getting more...

But the earth is also moving faster in its orbit during that time...

So maybe due to [Kepler's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law) it all equals out... ?

But then one might think, Kepler's second law is an idealized 2D law that applies to the earth's center of gravity, while the earth is actually more like a 3D sphere...

Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

The southern hemisphere does, for the reason you cite (the earth is a bit closer to the sun during the southern hemisphere summer). However, the effect is slight because the earth's orbit is nearly circular.

Comment: But what about the fact that the earth spends less total time closer to the sun than it does farther away?

Comment: That effect is small.